# Spring value populated with maven command line argument

Tags: spring, maven

I have the following configuration.

```
    @Configuration
    public class JasyptConfiguration {
    
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Value("${jasypt.encryptor.password}")
        private String jasyptEncryptorPassword;
    
        @Bean(name = "encryptorBean")
        public StringEncryptor stringEncryptor() {
            PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
            SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
            config.setPassword(jasyptEncryptorPassword);
         

   config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

And I would like to run maven project with following command line arguments.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
-Djasypt.encryptor.password=xxx
```

However spring cannot inject the second argument what is the proper structure ?

Comment: Hi. if you are using Spring Boot, it would be : mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--jasypt.encryptor.password=xxx (Spring Boot 2x) or mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--jasypt.encryptor.password=xxx (Spring Boot 1X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some changes to your java code to achieve this.
Instead of using @Value use @ConfigurationProperties like below

```
@ConfigurationProperties("jasypt.encryptor")
@Configuration
public class JasyptConfiguration {
    
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String password;   

...
}
```

Now in your application.properties or application.yml make below changes

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=${ENV_PASSWORD}
```

and when starting your app use

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -DENV_PASSWORD=xxx
```

Comment: How to add it as VM option in maven cli ?

Comment: you add the env variables to your mvn like
````
mvn clean package -DENV_PASSWORD=xxx
````